# Why am I getting the "Object reference not set to an instance of the object" exception?

Tags: visual-studio, exception, readline

**This is the piece of code where the exception is thrown:**

```
Private Sub btnNext_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnNext.Click
    File.OpenText("F:\CustomerRecords.txt")
    Dim customer As New CustomerRecord
    customer.strLastName = customersFile.ReadLine().ToString()
    lblLastName.Text = customer.strLastName
End Sub
```

Comment: What's `customersFile` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)